# Backup and restore column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to do a mass update to a column value. If there are issues I'll need to be able to revert the column back to it's previous value. So I'm backup the values to a temporary table.

BTW, I'm using Oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_trial_date_backup AS SELECT cust_id, trial_days FROM customer 
WHERE (trial_days = 0 or trial_days = -99)
```

Subsequently I'll perform the update.

```
UPDATE customer SET trial_days = 1 WHERE (trial_days = 0 or trial_days = -99)
```

My quest is... How can I restore the column values from the tmp table I've created ?do

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do a `ROLLBACK` in order to revert the change (i.e. why do you commit before checking if there are any issues?)

Comment: This change will got out live and therefore issues may not appear until perhaps 1 or 2 days. At this point I need a backout strategy.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I did the following.

```
UPDATE customer c SET trial_days = (SELECT trial_days from tmp_trial_days_backup 
where tmp_trial_days_backup.cust_id = customer_bond.cust_id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from tmp_trial_days_backup tmp WHERE tmp.cust_id = c.cust_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following update resets the trial_days from `customer` on a SQL Server database.

```
UPDATE  c
SET     trial_days = tmp.trial_days
FROM    customer c
        INNER JOIN tmp_trial_date_backup tmp ON tmp.cust_id = c.cust_id
```

Perhaps easier might have been to add a column `trial_days_backup` to the `customer` table.